# Django increment string value without race condition

Tags: mysql, django, transactions

On save I want to receive names like `name, name(1), name(2)`. I implemented the following code:

```
        with transaction.atomic():
            same_name_count = Folder.objects.filter(
                owner=validated_data["owner"],
                name__iregex=r"%s(\s\(\d+\))?" % validated_data["name"],
            ).count()

            if same_name_count:
                validated_data["name"] = f"{validated_data['name']} ({same_name_count+1})"

            folder = Folder.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

But I still receive race condition and receive same names when I run this code in celery task. I also tried `select_to_update` to lock all rows somehow and get correct count

My model looks like this:

```
class Folder(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: I don;t understand where race condition is. Can you provide an example what this code is outputting and what it should?

Comment: When I run 2 celery tasks with this code, I receive name with same number, e.g `name(1)` and `name(1)`. Of course this is only on production environment, when celery tasks CELERY_TASK_ALWAYS_EAGER=False

Comment: Can you share Folder model structure? What is owner field?

Comment: ```
class Folder(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('User')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: Update the question and put it there

Comment: Done. Thanks...

Comment: The idea is to have behaviour same as in Finder window. When we have object with same name, automatically add `(N)` prefix to the name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`select_for_update` will lock all selected rows in the table, but will not prevent adding new rows.

What you need to do is to lock row in other table. This way the transaction will wait until this locked row is unlocked.

In your case the most suitable is `User` table.

Here is example code:

```
    with transaction.atomic():
        # Assuming validated_data["owner"] is an id of the user. 
        # If its the User objects then add .id at the end
        folder_owner = User.objects.select_for_update().get(id=validated_data["owner"])

        same_name_count = Folder.objects.filter(
            owner=folder_owner,
            name__iregex=r"%s(\s\(\d+\))?" % validated_data["name"],
        ).count()

        if same_name_count:
            validated_data["name"] = f"{validated_data['name']} ({same_name_count+1})"

        folder = Folder.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: MySQL also has a feature for getting advisory locks, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locking-functions.html. This uses the same mechanism as table locks, but it doesn't lock any table or row.

Comment: Thanks, did't expect that I need to lock user to prevent inserting. It is working